# Why doesn't my compiler want to compile this code?

Tags: c, function, pointers, compilation

Yesterday I came across this problematic code that I have been meaning to understand and correct. So far I have done some research and corrected it, but I was wondering whether there are other ways to correct the code?

```
# include < stdio .h >
# include < stdlib .h >
int * sub ( int * x , int * y) { //return type should be pointer but is address//
int result = y - x ; //integer becomes pointer//
return &result;
}
int main ( void ) {
int x = 1;
int y = 5;
int * result = sub (&x , &y ); //function has addresses as parameters but not pointers//
printf ("% d\n" , * result );
return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
```

I would have simply deleted all pointers and addresses:

```
# include < stdio .h >
# include < stdlib .h >
int sub ( int x , int y) {
int result = y - x ;
return result ;
}
int main ( void ) {
int x = 1;
int y = 5;
int result = sub (x , y );
printf ("% d\n" , result );
return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
```

Comment: (a) When your compiler does not want to compile some code, it tells you why, in an error message. If you are having trouble understanding a message, you should include its exact text in your question. (b) `< stdio .h >` and `< stdlib .h >` are wrong because of the spaces. Remove the spaces. (c) Pointers are addresses, or at least the values of pointer objects are addresses in memory. A function that returns a pointer returns an address (or `NULL`). (d) It is not proper to return the address of `result` because `result` exists (in the C model of execution) only for the execution of `sub`.

Comment: In your first piece of code where you `return &result;`, you're returning a pointer to a local variable which is located in the stack. This is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the spaces in and around the import statements:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sub(int x, int y)
{
  int result = y - x;
  return result;
}

int main(void)
{
  int x = 1;
  int y = 5;
  int result = sub(x, y);
  printf("% d\n", result);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you come across this code? There is no need for the sub method, and no purpose for those pointers, in fact all of this code is redundant. Here is it 'fixed':

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    printf("4\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But this sounds suspiciously like a school assignment.

Comment: Probably was a school assignment, somebody uploaded it into a c-programming drive. Obviously I thought of this answer as well, however that person who uploaded it asked whether there was any way to place the pointers and adresses correctly. Therefore I replied to her that all of them could be deleted. My question was whether my explainations in the first code were correct.

Comment: Ok, in that case, apart from the weird spacing in the `#include`s and the lack of indentation, the code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Dereference the pointers and do some trickery with memory allocation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int *sub (int *x, int *y) {
    int *result = malloc(sizeof(*result));
    *result = *y - *x;
    return result;
}
int main (void) {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 5;
    int *result = sub(&x, &y);
    printf("%d\n", *result );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```